# Webcams on the same usb bus in ubuntu

Tags: opencv, usb, webcam, bandwidth

Probably a beginner's question, but I don't seem to be able to find the answer on google.

For computer vision purposes, I intend to process frames of two webcams on the same computer. 
I have some lagging issues, and I was investigating the fact that both webcams could be on the same usb bus. 
But I don't seem to be able to put those two webcams on different buses on ubuntu, although I tried all slots. 
I tried with three different webcams (logitech and microsoft) and two different motherboard, the last one being an asus Z97 pro gamer, which I assume has plenty of different usb buses.

All webcams always remain on bus 003. Is there something I don't understand about the bus system?

Thanks a lot for your input.

LSB output example below

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 2516:0003  
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 046d:082d Logitech, Inc. HD Pro Webcam C920
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0603:00f2 Novatek Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that you may not have considered is a bus is not always available through the external USB ports. Some of the buses may be dedicated internally, or have no header to bring them outside of the machine.

It appears that this may be the case with the machine you are using.

There are usually ways to add additional roots to the USB system. Depending on the machine you are using.

Comment: Interesting. Many thanks for your comments. I'll look into it and tell you what I got

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble remapping those buses. In the end, it was simpler to add a PCI express card that added some USB slots with their own tiny bus.